# When Did The Secret Wars Raft Survivors Meet?

Tags: marvel

In Secret Wars, there's a jump between issues 5 & 6 after Sheriff Strange scatters the Raft survivors, where Captain Marvel meets Baron Sinister, Thor gathers the Thor Corps and Reed meets Ultimate "Maker" Reed.

Did these did these characters meet in the spin-off comics, and if so, which ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I remember; survivors of 616 and 1610 didn't seen in spin-offs except Thors #5. In Thors #5, Thor Jane just made talk that we saw in Secret Wars #7. But we don't know details about how they meet with Mr. Sinister, Thor Corps yet.

Comment: Marking as accepted (I wanted to hold off and see if anybody had seen something else in a spin-off). Looks like another one of Hickman's patent time-skips.